# Emulator ugly font (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio

I am using Android Studio on Windows 10, but it is difficult to work with it because of the ugly font rendering. Here it is screen-shot.

[Open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjJbb.png)

Configuration device:

[Open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1De9.png)

how can I fix it?

Comment: Haven't used Android Studio in awhile, but looks like something with display scaling. Is the emulator sized (or can it even be sized) all the way up? Are you scaling your display in Windows Settings at all? Might be worth investing in a burner external device to do your testing if this bothers you a lot.

Comment: Full screen emulator is beautiful

Comment: my monitor is small, I can not always leave the emulator in full screen

Comment: I'm guessing you already played with different DPIs and resolutions. Windows 10 has [workspaces](https://www.howtogeek.com/197625/how-to-use-virtual-desktops-in-windows-10/). Good option if you don't have a second monitor. Maybe someone else can comment on a setting that could fix this.

Comment: It is not a solution

Comment: Correct. Comments are for discussion, answers are for solutions. Hopefully someone else can point you in a better direction.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue and fixed by matching my monitor's resolution with android emulator DPI.

[Android Emulator Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRsZ6.png)